# My Apache virtualhosts is acting up

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, xampp

my windows 7 hosts file has this...

```
127.0.0.1     www.testing.com
127.0.0.1    testing.com
```

and my apache http-vhosts.conf file has this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "E:/Server/htdocs/myframework"
ServerName testing.com
ServerAlias www.testing.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It almost works as I want it except it is wrong.
Now when I go to `"testing.com"` or `"www.testing.com"` it does load the `"E:/Server/htdocs/myframework"`  page as I want it to, however now when I got to `"localhost"` it always loads `"E:/Server/htdocs/myframework"` instead of `localhost/the-directory-i-want` or file i want

Anybody know why or better, how I can make it work how I would expect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have that one vhost set up then it will serve eveything. You could set up a localhost vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/Path/To/localhost"
    ServerName localhost
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also Your hosts file can have the hosts all on one line

```
127.0.0.1 www.testing.com testing.com localhost
```

Comment: thanks for the response and the tip on the 1 line for hosts,however, I have tried this and it still routes everything E:/Server/htdocs/myframework instead of E:/Server/htdocs/ ... any other ideas?  And yes I restarted Apache, thanks again